# Change label color on active inputbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Do someone know why this not work?
I want to change the color of the label from a input box when the box is active.

The JavaScript:

```
$("input").focus(function() {
var inputID = document.activeElement.id;
document.getAnonymousElementByAttribute('label','for', inputID).setAttribute('class', 'active');
});
```

The HTML:

```
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input name="username" id="username" type="text"><br>
<label for="passwort">Passwort</label>
<input name="passwort" id="passwort" type="password"><br>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="login">
```

The CSS:

```
.active{
    color: #FFA500 !important;
}
```

I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current HTML:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).prev().addClass('active');
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A8J3E/).

Or, with `on()` (assuming you're using jQuery 1.7, or above):

```
$('input').on('focus blur', function(e){
    var prev = $(this).prev();
    prev[e.type == 'focus' ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('active');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A8J3E/1/).

More abstracted (so the HTML stucture doesn't matter), selecting by the `for` attribute:

```
$('input').on('focus blur', function(e){
    var label = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]');
    label[e.type == 'focus' ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('active');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A8J3E/2/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).
- [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Comment: On JS Fiddle it works very fine, bur by me - nothing. The class will not be added. I use jquery-2.0.3. is that a problem?

Comment: You're very welcome, and well done for working out the problem yourself! :)

Answer (score 0):

See here for a very basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/zn5fB/

And here, for an event-triggered example: http://jsfiddle.net/zn5fB/1/

Setting a style with JavaScript usually follows the following format:

```
document.getElementById("abc").style.[css property name in camel case] = "[value]";
```

You will find that it is very common to use a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to make this (and many other things) a little easier. With jQuery, you can write code like:

```
// find all elements with the tag name "bar" that are direct 
// descendants of an element with the class name "foo"
$(".foo > BAR").css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').on('click', function(){
    $(label).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Your overcomplicating things, keep it simple, sometimes a developers most useful tool is the backspace key.

Answer (score 0):

Try `input:focus` instead of `.active` in your CSS code. Omit `!important` as well.

```
input:focus{
   color: #FFA500;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mix jQuery functions with non-jQuery. Try to use only jQuery functions to handle your task. In my example below I changed `.focus()` to `.on('focus',callback)` which is same but just more understandable. In jQuery you should get target of your event and wrap it by `$()`. You also can use `this` but I try not to use it by several reasons. Then you can apply any of many jQuery methods:

```
$("input").on('focus', function(ev) {
    var t = $(ev.target);
    t.addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Hi, your post has been flagged as "low quality", probably because it consists solely of code. You could massively improve your answer by providing an explanation of exactly how and why this answers the question?